# How to load interceptors and services from app module to lazy loaded module?

Tags: angular, angular6

```
I have loaded some interceptors and services in app.module.ts and want to 
load same interceptors and services in lazy loaded module.how do i load 
it?This is app.module.ts file where i have loaded interceptors and 
services in providers.
@NgModule({

providers: [
{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoaderInterceptor, multi: true },
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CommonInterceptor, multi: true },
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ServerErrorsInterceptor, multi: 
true },
CommonServiceService, 
dialogModelService, 
LoaderService, 
LoginServiceService, 
MessageService,
ValidationService,
AuthGuard,
{ provide: USER_STORAGE, useExisting: SESSION_STORAGE },
    UserStorageService
],
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

when the internal modules are loading inside the pages folder. interceptors and services are not working in modules which are lazy loaded

[image]

Comment: in what module did you place your http services?

Comment: i have a service which i have imported in lazy loaded module but all service will go through the interceptors which i have already defined in app.module file . but when the service is calling . interceptors are not working

Comment: can you include your service module here

Comment: i cant be able to put the other images. but i will explain you . the interceptors which i have used in app.module file. the same code i have to write providers in lazy loaded module . suppose page module is the lazy loaded module. and in page module i have different other modules which is loded lazyly. so the interceptors code i have to write it again and again.

Answer (score 0):

All services `provided` in the app.module.ts should have global scope, meaning, you can use them for dependency injection in any lazy loaded module without errors throughout the application

If you HOWEVER want to have **separate provider instances** for lazy loaded modules, just add it into the `providers` array of the respective @NgModule

Comment: i have loaded all the interceptors and services in app.module and it has a global scope but still not loading in lazy loaded module

Comment: share your specific error/problem, why do you think it is not loading?

Comment: i have a service which i have imported in lazy loaded module but all service will go through the interceptors which i have already defined in app.module file . but when the service is calling . interceptors are not working